# MySQL 5.5 not starting after master-master configuration

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5

The following `master-master` configuration worked on MySQL Server 5.1.x(Ubuntu 10.04).

### Master1(192.168.2.80)

```
##################################
#MySQL Replication
##################################
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
event_scheduler = ON
max_connections = 500
max_connect_errors = 1000

server-id = 10
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 10
auto-increment-offset = 1

master-host = 192.168.2.81
master-user = repli
master-password = secret
master-connect-retry = 60

binlog-format = MIXED
#binlog-ignore-db = information_schema
#binlog-ignore-db = lb1

#max_binlog_size = 500M
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/bin-log.index

log-slave-updates
report-host = 192.168.2.80
replicate-ignore-db = information_schema
replicate-ignore-db = lb2
replicate-ignore-db = performance_schema

relay_log_space_limit = 3G
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/relay-log.index
##################################
```

### Master2(192.168.2.81)

```
##################################
#MySQL Replication
##################################
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
event_scheduler = ON
max_connections = 500
max_connect_errors = 1000

server-id = 20
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 10
auto-increment-offset = 2

master-host = 192.168.2.80
master-user = repli
master-password = secret
master-connect-retry = 60

binlog-format = MIXED
#binlog-ignore-db = information_schema
#binlog-ignore-db = lb2

#max_binlog_size = 500M
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/bin-log.index

log-slave-updates
report-host = 192.168.2.81
replicate-ignore-db = information_schema
replicate-ignore-db = lb1
replicate-ignore-db = performance_schema

relay_log_space_limit = 3G
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/relay-log.index
##################################
```

Now it's NOT working on MySQL Server 5.5(ubuntu 12.04). I mean to say when I restart the mysql service after above configuration, mysql server takes long time and dont' start at all. Nothing in mysql logs and are empty. I tried killing mysql and starting it again but still it's not starting and if I remove the above master-master replication configuration then it starts usually. What's wrong I am doing with mysql 5.5?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What's the exact version of 5.5 you're running.  If you're running 5.5.24 you might be running into this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1008278.

If you are running 5.5.24 ensure userstat=OFF.  Really though this is annoying so you might look at just upgrading beyond that.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it's 5.5.24. When I tried `set global userstat=0;` in the mysql shell, it gives the error `ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'userstat'`

Comment: Apologies, my comment was related to the percona specific builds. If you're running the community edition through Ubuntu's package manager it would be expected this variable is unavailable.  Consequently my initial suggestion was misplaced.

Comment: You list different server ids in your opening post.  On the chance you scrubbed them for public posting, you might double check they aren't really the same in your cnfs.  Conflicting server ids is known to wreak havoc in replication.

Comment: Also, I realize you said there's nothing in your error logs, but on the off chance you weren't looking at the droid you thought you were looking for, double check the directory/file permissions/ownership of every path related config variable.